# How to quickly generate an RSA Keypair for React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, public-key-encryption

I'm attempting to generate an RSA keypair for React Native (Expo) and I'm having no luck. I tried using the keypair NPM package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypair) but when I try to generate the keypair it freezes the app for around 30 seconds, even when I make the bit size something like 64 bits. I'm trying to generate the keypair on a button press on my login screen, and the app takes an unacceptable amount of time to navigate to the home screen. I ran the command on node on my desktop and it takes about 1 second, and the function isn't asynchronous. Is there a better way to generate this keypair, or is there some better algorithm/method to generate a keypair on mobile?

I am already using expo-crypto for password hashing but I couldn't find anything about generating key pairs.